# How to redirect example.com/company to example.com?name=company?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, jboss

I have a web application running in JBoss on `www.example.com:8080/webapp`. I want users to be able to use the URL `www.example.com/company` and have that redirected to `www.example.com:8080/webapp?name=company` in order to present company specific logos and names for each client.

Can I do this using the rewrite engine? and use Apache as the redirect to JBoss?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, then give the following rewrite a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com:8080/webapp?name=$1 [R, 301]
```